# MongoDB Node Express GET and DELETE work, not POST?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

GET works.
DELETE works.

Can't figure out why POST won't work with something as simple as.

```
{"akey":"avalue"}
```

Using Postman to test. The error from Postman is "Could not get any response," which is weird, because I have no problems with GET and DELETE.

New to Mongo/Node. Following Brad Traversy's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j55fHUJqtyw tutorial on Vue, Mongo, Express, Node.

Anything stand out?

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const mongodb = require( 'mongodb' );

const router = express.Router();

// GET POSTS
router.get( '/', async ( req, res ) => {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
    res.send( await posts.find( {} ).toArray() );
} );

// ADD POST
router.post( '/', async ( req, res ) => {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
    await posts.insertOne( {
                               text: req.body.text
                           } );
    res.status(201).send();
} );

// DEL POST
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res)=>{
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
        await posts.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.id)});
        res.status(200).send();
})

async function loadPostsCollection() {
    const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect( 'mongodb+srv://someUser:somePassword@some-bkebp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
        useNewUrlParser   : true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    } );
    return client.db( 'someDB' ).collection( 'somCollection' )
}

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Reason

It seems like your `await posts.insertOne({ text: req.body.text });` never ends (or crashes and express doesn't respond), so Postman never gets the response.

Try `console.log`ing after your `await` to see if it's the root cause of the problem.

## Possible solution

Try something this way to handle errors about your db requests

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
    await posts.insertOne({
      text: req.body.text
    });
    res.status(201).send(); // You may need to answer something here
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return res.status(500).end() // 500 is INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can put some logic to handle errors there may be useful information there.

```
// ADD POST
router.post( '/', async ( req, res ) => {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
    await posts.insertOne( {
                           text: req.body.text
                       })
    .then(result => if (result) res.status(201).send());  // handle success case
    .catch(err => { //see what the error is
        console.error; 
        res.status(500)
        res.render('error', { error: err })
        })
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it just times out still and "could not get any response" is all I get at the end.